# Test type of elements python tuple/list

Tags: python

How do you verify that the type of all elements in a list or a tuple are the same and of a certain type?

for example:

```
(1, 2, 3)  # test for all int = True
(1, 3, 'a') # test for all int = False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python check if all elements of a list are the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252333/python-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-the-same-type)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
all(isinstance(n, int) for n in lst)
```

Demo:

```
In [3]: lst = (1,2,3)

In [4]: all(isinstance(n, int) for n in lst)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: lst = (1,2,'3')

In [6]: all(isinstance(n, int) for n in lst)
Out[6]: False
```

Instead of `isinstance(n, int)` you could also use `type(n) is int`

Comment: The OP should be warned that this can lead to unexpected behaviour in Python 2, because isinstance(10**100, int) == False.  You'd need to do isinstance(n, (int, long)).  But in Python, needing to check the type of something is often a sign of a design mistake to start with.

Comment: Also, `type()` returns `<type 'instance'>` for old-style classes.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the expression `all(test(i) for i in list)`: instead of returning a `bool`, it returns a generator expression. Is this something version specific?

Comment: short and precise.

Answer (score 8):

```
all(isinstance(i, int) for i in your_list))
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you're doing it may be more Pythonic to use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). That way, things that are int-like (floats, etc.) can be passed as well as ints. In this case, you might try converting each item in the tuple to an `int`, and then catch any exceptions that arise:

```
>>> def convert_tuple(t, default=(0, 1, 2)):
...     try:
...         return tuple(int(x) for x in t)
...     except ValueError, TypeError:
...         return default
...
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
>>> convert_tuple((1.1, 2.2, 3.3))
(1, 2, 3)
>>> convert_tuple((1.1, 2.2, 'f'))
(0, 1, 2)
>>> convert_tuple((1.1, 2.2, 'f'), default=(8, 9, 10))
(8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check type of elements using 'type' function in python like-

```
>>> all(type(n) == int for n in last) # [1, 2, 2, 34]
True
>>> all(type(n) == str for n in last) # [1, 2, 2, 34]
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Only to mention the possibility, you can avoid list comprehension with:

```
all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), your_list))
```