# Type of all elements in Python list

Tags: python

Is there a way to quickly print out the type of **all** the elements of some given list in Python?

For example `[1, 2, 3.5]` would give `int, int, float`.

The closest existing resource I've found to answering my question is: [Test type of elements python tuple/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964191/test-type-of-elements-python-tuple-list), which just gives holistic True/False outputs (which is not what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for l in lst:
    print(type(l))
```

Where `lst = [1,2,3.5]`

Answer (score 6):

If you are really interested in types of all elements in your list then you can use this expression:

```
list(type(x).__name__ for x in lst)
```

If you only want to know how many *different types* are in your list you can use this:

```
set(type(x).__name__ for x in lst)
```

Comment: Can you explain how the `__name__` attribute operates here?

Comment: `type(x)` returns the *type object*, whose `__name__` attribute provides the *type name*.

Answer (score 2):

In python, [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function is used to find the datatype of a variable.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3.5]
>>> [type(i) for i in l]
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>]
>>> [str(type(i)).split("'")[1] for i in l]
['int', 'int', 'float']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  mylist = [1, 1, 1.5]
  map(lambda x: repr(type(x)), mylist)
```